# Understanding C++ DLL mapping to C# with unions

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, dll, unions

I have the following scenario. I have a struct with a union in a DLL written in C++ and I need to map this structure to C# code. Please, have in mind that I cannot change the code in the DLL. Here is a sample code to illustrate what is happening:

```
  typedef struct {
    int type;
    union {
        int val;
        double val2;
        char *name;
    };
  } BIZARRE;

  __declspec(dllexport) void changeBizarre(BIZARRE *bizarre, int type, const char *v)
  {
      bizarre->type = type;
      if(type == 0) {
          bizarre->val = 5;
      } else if(type == 1) {
          bizarre->val2 = 2.0;
      } else if(type == 2) {
          strncpy(bizarre->name, "test", strlen("test"));
      } else if(type == 3 && strcmp(v, "test") == 0) {
          bizarre->val = 10;
      }    
  }
```

And in the C# code, I've done the following:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public unsafe struct BIZARRE
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int type;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public int val;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public double val2;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public char *name;
}

[DllImport("proj.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public unsafe static extern void changeBizarre(ref BIZARRE bizarre, int type, char *name);

unsafe static void Main()
{
   char[] v = "test".ToCharArray();
   bizarre.type = 0;
   bizarre.val = 0;
   bizarre.val2 = 0.0;
   fixed (char* address = v)
   {
     bizarre.name = address;
     changeBizarre(ref bizarre, 3, &bizarre.name);
     Console.WriteLine("{0}", bizarre.val);
   }
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Now, if you run this code by passing type = 2, and try to print the bizarre.name, it will appear junk characters and if you pass type = 3, apparently the DLL is not being able to get the content pointed by bizarre.name, I do believe these two behaviors have the same cause, but I don't know what is it.

Comment: That is a dangerous game, it is very easy to get the C++ code to corrupt the GC heap.  It doesn't work because you used char[] instead of byte[] and the string is not zero-terminated.  The pinvoke marshaller is powerless to make the proper conversion since it cannot know which field is being used.

Comment: I'm using a char[] v and passing a string to it, which has a '\0' in the end. So, the string is zero-terminated. And in the DLL it is being used a char *, so I think it would better represent the purpose of the code by passing a char array in C#. I've also tested your solution and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The `char` array is not a real `char` array in C, in fact C# will use `wchar_t` type (16 bit char).

Change your C code using `wchar_t` stuff:

```
typedef struct {
    int type;
    union {
        int val;
        double val2;
        wchar_t *name;
    };
} BIZARRE;

__declspec(dllexport) void changeBizarre(BIZARRE *bizarre, int type, const wchar_t *v)
{
    bizarre->type = type;
    if (type == 0) {
        bizarre->val = 5;
    }
    else if (type == 1) {
        bizarre->val2 = 2.0;
    }
    else if (type == 2) {
        wcsncpy(bizarre->name, L"test", wcslen("test"));
    }
    else if (type == 3 && wcscmp(v, L"test") == 0) {
        bizarre->val = 10;
    }
}
```

## Or

Change your C# code using the `byte` type instead of `char` (as mentioned @Hans Passant) :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public unsafe struct BIZARRE
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int type;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public int val;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public double val2;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public byte* name;
}


class Program
{

    [DllImport("UnionMapping_dll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public unsafe static extern void changeBizarre(ref BIZARRE bizarre, int type, byte* name);

    static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BIZARRE bizarre;
        byte[] v = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test");
        bizarre.type = 0;
        bizarre.val = 0;
        bizarre.val2 = 0.0;
        fixed (byte* address = v)
        {
            bizarre.name = address;
            changeBizarre(ref bizarre, 3, bizarre.name);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", bizarre.val);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't say it before, but I can't change the code of the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ code has a union within a struct - your C# equivalent for interop purposes should reflect that:

```
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

  public struct BIZARRE
  {
    public int type;
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct AnonymousStruct
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int val;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public double val2;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public string name;
    }
  }
```

Comment: If I try to use string, it gives me the following error " it contains an object field at offset 8 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.". I do believe I must change the FieldOffset of the string, but to what value ? And why it happens ?

Comment: @Vinicius: Perhaps go back to your original char pointer for the 'name' field.

Comment: Going back to the original char pointer has the same behavior as in the original code I have posted.